# How to use a non default schema with syncdb Django

Tags: django, postgresql

Is there a way to tweak django to create a new schema with specific name when using syncdb or reset.

Comment: Are you saying django should create the schema in postgres when do syncdb instead of you creating it yourself?

Comment: (Adding to Meitham's comment): Or do only you want syncdb to write the new tables into a non-default schema (which might exist already)?

Comment: yes it's what I'm looking for, into a non-default schema

Comment: You did not clarify: does the non-default schema exist, yet? Do you want to create it manually or do you want Django to create it?

Comment: I want it create all the shema with table that correpond to my model a normal behaviour but with a particular schema name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Django, but if it doesn't provide a way then you can set the `search_path` on a per-user basis. If Django doesn't know about schemas, it'll just use whatever you set as the default:

```
ALTER USER my_user SET search_path = new_schema;
```

Comment: I will test with Django but I think it could be the trick I need. But with that I will need one postgres user by django app.